# gradleにて作成したjarファイルの中のテンプレート参照がうまくいきません。

Tags: excel, spring-boot, gradle, apache-poi, jar

【バージョン関連】
springBoot：2.1.0.RELEASE
Gradle：4.8.1
poi：3.17
java:8

spring bootにて、poiを使ったエクセルファイルの取り扱いをしております。
Controllerクラスにて、「ExcelBuilder/files/template.xlsx」を参照していますが、
jarファイルにて実行するとresource変数がnullとなってしまいます。

intellijにてアプリケーションを実行すると、問題なく動くのですが、
jarファイルにした場合は、何か考慮すべきことがあるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

```
try {

  Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:files/template.xlsx");

  mav = new ModelAndView(new ExcelBuilder(resource.getFile()));

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.getStackTrace();
}
```

ExcelBuilderにFileを渡して、Excel操作しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

Ideとjarではファイルの読み込み方を変えなければならないとのことでした。
下記、変更後のコードです。
ありがとうございました。

```
File file = null;
String resourceStr = "/files/template.xlsx";
URL res = getClass().getResource(resourceStr);

// IDE実行とjarファイル実行で分岐させる
if (res.toString().startsWith("jar:")) {
  try {
    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceStr);
    file = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");

    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(input, file);

    file.deleteOnExit();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
  }
} else {
  // IDE用
  file = new File(res.getFile());
}

if (file != null && !file.exists()) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Error: File " + file + " not found!");
}
mav = new ModelAndView(new ExcelBuilder(file));

return mav;
```

Comment: 「IDE実行とjarファイル実行で分岐させる」ようなコードは入れ無い方がいいと思います（入れる必要もないはずです）。